# Bootstrap navbar glitching while trying to make it collapsible

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, visual-glitch

I got a sample code of a *navigation bar* from w3schools.com. It is using **bootstrap**. Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

This navbar is working perfectly fine.
But for small screens(case of *collapsible* navbar) I want the navbar to collapse **when I click on an option in it**. So, I added `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"` in all the `<li>`. Now the navbar is properly toggling for small screens.

Here is a vid of the issue:
[image]

Here is the modified code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"  href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

But now, the whole navbar is glitching for large screens(desktop). Please help in resolving this.

Do point out if this is replication, as I am not able to find that.

The final HTML code that is glitching for desktop screens is down below(same problem in google-chrome, firefox, brave):

```html
<html>
  <title>Example</title>    
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"  href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"  href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
      
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
      <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
      <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Click on **expand snippet** to see the glitch on the desktop screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a **better way** to collapse the navbar! Why not include some lines of **JS** as you are already using jQuery, like this-

```js
$('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<title>Example</title>

<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container">
      <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
      <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
        <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
</body>
```